# Creating a Collection to return from a generic method

Tags: java, generics

Caveat: Yes, I know that I could make the calling methods use Collection rather that a sub-class or cast the Collection or several other things.  And will probably do that while waiting for answers.  But I'm curious if this is possible and my Google-fu isn't getting me anywhere. :-)

So I have a method which has either a Set or a List as a parameter and the returns a new one of the same (and, yes, there are other sub-classes of Collection, but these are the two I will see).  So I tried using generics:

```
private <T extends Collection<String>> T doStuff(T input) {
  T output = (input instanceof List) 
    ? new ArrayList<String>() 
    : new HashSet<String>();
  // do stuff to fill output from input
  return output;
}
```

This version has red ink saying that I can't convert an ArrayList to T.  I tried variations on this with no luck.  Any thoughts?

EDIT: Thanks for humoring my curiosity. I will of course be using something simpler like just returning a Collection, but it is good to know what the issue was for future reference.

Comment: So what would you want returned if I pass in a `TreeSet` of a non-comparable type?

Comment: I'd suggest overload this method for one that accepts a `List` as parameter and another to accept a `Set` as parameter.

Comment: This cannot work. Java's generic type system is not this fancy

Comment: Your best option is to return `Collection` and then make a copy of it using the right type of `T`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid the compilation error, you must instantiate an object of type T which is not possible in Java because of the type erasure. I suggest using two overloaded methods instead of a generic one.

Comment: Yes, this would be my approach too; however, this requires this method to be called "directly". For example, if the call to `doStuff` is itself in a generic method, this wouldn't allow one or other method to be invoked selectively.

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering if there was some underlying thing like that which was the root cause.  I appreciate the information.

Answer (score 0):

Let `S extends Collection<String>` be the abstract type of the collection you'd like to return from your method, i.e. `List` or `Set`.

Let `C extends S` be the runtime-type of the returned result, i.e. `ArrayList` or `HashSet`.

In order to get an instance of `C` at compile-time, you will have to explicitly provide a `Class<C>` instance, as an argument.

So, the method becomes:

```
public <S extends Collection<String>, C extends S> S doStuff(S input, Class<C> clazz) throws Exception {
    C output = clazz.newInstance();
    // do stuff to fill output from input
    return output;
}
```

You'd be able to call this methods with:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>() {{ add("Hello"); }};
doStuff(list, ArrayList.class);

Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>() {{ add("World"); }};
doStuff(set, HashSet.class);
```

Of course, you should take care of the checked exceptions that might be thrown from the `clazz.newInstance()` callback.

Comment: Hmm, this didn't actually work for me.  Says that A cannot be resolved to a type.  Changing A to C cleaned up the method, but it did not return the appropriate type (i.e. either a List<String> or Set<String>).  Thanks for the thoughts though.

Comment: @ScottLaw, sorry, updated the answer. Now it should be fine.

Answer (score -2):

If you're *really* able to return a Collection, that means you only need the Collection interface, and you don't care about the speed/size trade-offs of the various Collection subclasses.

If that's truly the case, then it doesn't matter whether you return a List or a Set, regardless of which you're called with. So just do that:

```
private Collection doStuff(Collection input) {
  // do stuff to fill output from input
  return new ArrayList(input);
  // or, return new HashSet(input);
}
```

If you, or your callers, do actually care about the methods (or speed/size guarantees) of particular Collection subclasses, then you'll need to overload on the actual subclasses of interest.

Note of course that overload resolution is determined at compile time using static (reference) types, not the dynamic types actually pointed to at runtime.

Comment: Please see caveat.